# How can I get object fill by SignalR Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

This is my problem :

I want call signalR function from controller to get list of users connected. 
In my OnConnected(), OnDisconnected method I collect the correct data but when I create my own method i can't get the list of Users.

I feel I have a problem with my context because my list is empty but I don't know really why.

I have try somes test :

This a counter of number users connected in my application with SignalR.
The list of users is fill with the OnConnected() method and clean with OnDisconnected()

OnConnected() an user is add:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            var currentCollab = Context.User.Identity.Name.Length > 0 ? Context.User.Identity.Name : "";
            var module = Context.QueryString["module"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module))
            {
                SignalRUsers.Add(new UserConnected()
                {
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    UserName = currentCollab,
                    ModuleActif = module
                });
            }


            await Clients.All.UpdateCountAccueil(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)));

            await base.OnConnected();
        }
```

In this method `SignalRUsers` the list is filled with all previous connections but as soon as I try to retrieve the values from this list in a method to call it in my controller this list is completely empty (while there are many active connections)

Complete *Hub Class :*

```
using System;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Util;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConvergenceCore.ServiceSettingsManager;
using ConvergenceDataAccess.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Main
{

    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static long counterAccueil = 0;
        private static long counterParam = 0;


        static Dictionary<string, int> CurrentConnections = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        static List<UserConnected> SignalRUsers = new List<UserConnected>();


        public void Send(string module, string etat, string message)
        {

            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(module, etat, message);
        }


        public override async Task OnReconnected()
        {

            var currentCollab = Context.User.Identity.Name.Length > 0 ? Context.User.Identity.Name : "";
            var module = Context.QueryString["module"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module))
            {
                SignalRUsers.Add(new UserConnected()
                {
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    UserName = currentCollab,
                    ModuleActif = module
                });
            }

            await Clients.All.UpdateCountAccueil(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountParam(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountRh(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountFacturation(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)));


            await base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            var currentCollab = Context.User.Identity.Name.Length > 0 ? Context.User.Identity.Name : "";
            var module = Context.QueryString["module"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module))
            {
                SignalRUsers.Add(new UserConnected()
                {
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    UserName = currentCollab,
                    ModuleActif = module
                });
            }


            await Clients.All.UpdateCountAccueil(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountParam(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountRh(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountFacturation(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)));

            await base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var userToDelete = SignalRUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
            SignalRUsers.Remove(userToDelete);
            //CurrentConnections.Remove(module + Context.ConnectionId);

            await Clients.All.UpdateCountAccueil(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Accueil.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountParam(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Param.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountRh(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Rh.Value)));
            await Clients.All.UpdateCountFacturation(SignalRUsers.Count(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)), SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif.ToUpper().Equals(ModuleName.Facturation.Value)));

            await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);

        }

        public List<UserConnected> GetListUsersConnected(string module)
        {
            return SignalRUsers.Where(x => x.ModuleActif == module).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class UserConnected
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
        public string ModuleActif { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my  *Controller :*

```
 public PartialViewResult DetailUsersConnected(string module)
        {
           ChatHub hub = new ChatHub();
           var listUsers = hub.GetListUsersConnected(module);

            return PartialView("../Parametrages/Content/_DetailsUserConnected", listUsers);
        }
```

Why is my list empty in my GetListUsersConnected method ?

Why I do not recover met previous connection as in OnConnected() for example ?

Comment: You must protect your SignalRUsers list against multiple threads. Because multiple threads may try to manipulate it, which may cause data loss. you may use lock(SignalRUsers) and use the list inside this block.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a client connects a new instance of the Hub object is created. If your SignalRUsers is a property of the hub, then is created from scratch every time. Try make it a static property or use a Singleton in a container.

Comment: Why OnConnected can get all users connected so ?

Comment: Could you share the complete hub class?